GCC optimizing with -Os incorrectly assumes pointer to be NULL
Recently we switched to a more recent GCC and it optimized away a whole function and replaced it with "null pointer access" trap code instead when optimizing for size. Looking at godbolt, the issue appeared with GCC 11.1 when optimizing with -Os. Optimizing with -O2 and -O3 works fine, even with -fstrict-aliasing.
Simplified, the code looks like this (godbolt link):
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct bounds_s {
  uint8_t *start;
  uint8_t *end;
} bounds_s_t;

static void reserve_space(bounds_s_t *bounds, size_t len, uint8_t **element)
{
  if (bounds->start + len > bounds->end) {
    return;
  }
  
  *element = bounds->start;
  bounds->start += len;
}

void bug(uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)
{
  bounds_s_t bounds;
  uint32_t *initialize_this;
  
  initialize_this = NULL;
  bounds.start = buffer;
  bounds.end = buffer + size;

  reserve_space(&bounds, sizeof(*initialize_this), (uint8_t **)&initialize_this);

  uint32_t value = 1234;
  memcpy(initialize_this, &value, sizeof(*initialize_this));
}

And leads to the following assembly:
bug:
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR ds:0, eax
        ud2

What optimization makes GCC think that the initialize_this variable is NULL? The only thing that comes to my mind is breaking strict aliasing rules. But can typecasting double pointers from uint32_t ** to uint8_t ** really be the issue here and lead to such heavy consequences?

the memcpy is basically intended to be an *initialize_this = 1234 with alignment checks.

Are you compiling with -Wall and / or -Wstrict-aliasing and / or -Wstrict-aliasing=3?  It's risky to compile with strict-aliasing optimization enabled but related warnings disabled.

Does compiling with -fno-strict-aliasing resolve the issue?  Levels -Os, -O2, and -O3 are all inclusive of -fstrict-aliasing, so enabling it explicitly in combination with one of those does not give you any new information, but disabling it might do.

Optimizing with -O2 and -O3 works fine, even with -fstrict-aliasing.  "I didn't observe any failures.  Today.  In my limited testing.  Right now.  Not yet, anyway." is not the same as "works fine".

@JohnBollinger Of course adding -fno-strict-aliasing resolves the issue. But I would have expected -O2 and -O3 to be affected by this "optimization" as well. Thats why the question is here in the first place, I was unsure about the origin of the error.

That -fno-strict-aliasing does resolve the issue would have been relevant information to include in the question.  That's why my comment is there.  I see no "of course" in that regard, at least not without first analyzing the code to actually find the strict-aliasing violation that turns out in fact to be there.  And note well that the issue is not the pointer conversion that you mention itself -- it is the manner in which the converted result is used, combined with other factors.

What do you expect the assembler code to be?  What is wrong with that assembler code?  Can you edit and put the complete code for bug ???

*element = bounds->start; violates strict aliasing:

Since element has type uint8_t **, *element has type uint8_t *, so this is storing into *element with type uint8_t *.
At this point, element has the address of initialize_this, which has declared type, and hence effective type, uint32_t *.
Accessing a uint32_t * with a type of uint8_t * does not conform to any of the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7.
In GCC, -fstrict-aliasing is enabled by -Os.
Therefore, the compiler is allowed to conclude, since it sees no write to a type that may alias uint32_t * after initialize_this = NULL;, that initialize_this is unchanged from a null pointer.

Additionally, there is no control in the code to ensure the value of bounds->start is an address properly aligned for a uint32_t.
These problems can be fixed:

The caller to reserve_space should also pass an alignment requirement, which can be computed by the calling using _Alignof (uint32_t *) (and, with the expected forthcoming C standard, _Alignof (typeof (initialize_this))). reserve_space should add padding bytes as necessary to make the starting address a multiple of this requirement.
Instead of having a parameter of type uint8_t **, reserve_space should return a void * pointing to the reserved space. The calling routine may then assign this to initialize_this, and the implicit conversion of assignment will automatically convert it to the correct type.

The code also does not show the origins of buffer. If it is dynamically allocated space, then, once initialize_this is properly set as described above, *initialize_this may be used as an ordinary uint32_t. In particular, there is no need to use memcpy to copy a value into it; it may be set with *initialize_this = 1234;. However, if buffer is created in some other way, such as a declared array of uint8_t, then aliasing problems may remain.

Additionally to the immediate aliasing and alignment issues of the pointers, there could be another set of such issues if an attempt were made to use *initialize_this to access the contents of the provided buffer, depending on what buffer actually points to.  The example does not contain such an access, but it is reasonable to infer that it was inspired by code that does.

Note that the authors of the Standard expected implementations to--on a quality of implementation basis--extend the semantics of the language beyond the bare miniuma established by the Standard by behaving usefully in more cases than mandated, and it would have been considered obvious that a quality compiler that can see that a uint32_t** is converted to a uint8_t** when passed to a function that might modify storage a that address would allow for the possibility that the called function might modify a uint32_t*.  Commercial compilers recognize that--just not free ones.
